# Is there a way to call a cryptographic library from inside the ink! contract?

Tags: ink, rust

This is one such link containing some examples of ink! contracts from parity's repo : https://github.com/paritytech/ink-examples/blob/main/rand-extension/lib.rs

Is there a way to call a custom function from a library, say a cryptographic library from the ink contract?

How to go about doing this?

I tried to add all the code I had from the library inside the ink! contract and it could work, but it is one heck of a tedious task and I don't think it is the correct way either.

Answer (score 2):

Cryptographic libraries are usually really heavy in terms of size (and contacts should be smaller as possible).
You can already checks [here](https://paritytech.github.io/ink/ink_env/#functions) if the function you need is already implemented.

If not it should be implemented in the runtime and be called from the contract:

- either add it to pallet-contracts (like it has been implemented for ECDSA crypto)
- or via chain-extension calling an specific pallet (but it will depends on the L1)

Comment: L1 is parachain. Every parachain will have its own set of chain-extensions